# Cant update pdf file using pdf-lib nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

How to update pdf file in nodejs using the pdf-lib?

documentation https://pdf-lib.js.org/

```
  const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(
    readFileSync(
      './UserAccount.pdf',
    ),
  );
  const form = pdfDoc.getForm();
  const applicationFor = form
    .getTextField('username')
    .setText('New Username');
  const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
  download(pdfBytes, 'pdf-lib_form_creation_example.pdf', 'application/pdf');
  return pdfBytes;
};
```

here is the text field property that I want to update on pdf

[image]